# Como redimensionar imagens antes de upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Boa tarde pessoal, minha aplicação já faz o upload de imagens usando o `<input type="file">`, mas somente imagens que forem menor que 2mb. estou armazenando o  `target.result` no banco e retornando em uma `<img>`. Um arquivo acima de 2mb da um erro de serialização ou excede o limite da requisição. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de reduzir a imagem antes de fazer a requisição ajax, em javascript. estou pesquisando e se eu encontrar eu posto aqui.

Comment: Eu fiz um sistema desses que removia até o EXIF da imagem, no select selecionava a imagem e repassava ela pra um CANVAS com tamanho determinado dinamicamente por JAVASCRIPT. Logo no Canvas bastou pegar o conteudo em BASE64 e upar a String no conteudo de um arquivo. O nome da imagem também pode ser adquirido por Javascript. Eu vou recriar esse sistema e coloco aqui, mas eu vou confirmar tudo que falei antes. (Eu não usei JQuery por que morria de medo de mexer com APIs na época)

Comment: Eu estava estudando o uso de APIs, mas por cautela de alguns superiores em relação a integridade das imagens não pude continuar o estudo. Vou dar uma olhada nesse método de CANVAS.